# Can I run 2 instances of Counter Strike Source on 1 computer?

Tags: counter-strike-source

What I wanted to do is to have a [deathmatch](http://www.bailopan.net/cssdm/) server set up on one instance, then join on that server using the other Source client on the same computer. Is this possible?

Comment: https://hourboost.com/index.php#products this website verifies that it works.

Comment: No, the games servers run through steam servers. In which case it would only allow you to be in game in one instance.

Comment: @P1raten, thanks I'll look into that.

Comment: @CrabtasticGoat, I see. But what if I copy the downloaded files from Steam then open one instance from the new directory, possibly without logging in to Steam, I only wanted to play on LAN by the way.

Comment: If you were playing LAN you could do that to run two copies maybe in offline mode? Give that a try.

Comment: I am playing on LAN. I tried opening both in offline mode, but "Cannot run 2 instances" error popped up, was wondering if there are any workaround.